# setTimeout() not working when I add img.style.opacity

Tags: javascript, settimeout, opacity

I have two pictures overlayed on top of one another in my HTML file, and want to switch their opacity every 3 seconds in the JS file so it switches between them. I tested the JS file without the "img.style.opacity" and it looped between the functions just fine. Looked like this..

```
function Step1(){
    alert("Step 1");    

    setTimeout(Step2(), 3000);
}

function Step2(){
    alert("Step 2");

    setTimeout(Step1(), 3000);
}
```

And it showed "Step 1" > "Step 2" > "Step 1" an so on every 3 seonds.

Then I added a little, and now it looks like this.

```
var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
var img2 = document.getElementById('img2');

function Step1(){
    // alert("Step 1"); 
    img1.style.opacity = "0";
    img2.style.opacity = "1";
    setTimeout(Step2(), 3000);
}

function Step2(){
    //alert("Step 2");
    img1.style.opacity = "1";
    img2.style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(Step1(), 3000);
}
```

And now it will only run Step1(), and doesn't go into Step2() at all.

Kinda new to JS, so sorry if the answer is something crazy simple.

Comment: `setTimeout(Step2(), 3000)` will call `Step2` ***immediately***. `setTimeout(Step2, 3000)` will call it in three seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, both `Step2()` and `Step1()` are being invoked as soon as `Step1()` and `Step2()` are called, respectively. There is no 3 second wait.

You should be passing a function to `setTimeout()` by reference (I.E: Without parenthesis):

```
var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
var img2 = document.getElementById('img2');

function Step1(){
    // alert("Step 1"); 
    img1.style.opacity = "0";
    img2.style.opacity = "1";
    setTimeout(Step2, 3000);
}

function Step2(){
    //alert("Step 2");
    img1.style.opacity = "1";
    img2.style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(Step1, 3000);
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/faemf5L2/)

Comment: Well that's kind of frustrating. Clearly it should be working! I literally copy/pasted that into my file and still it refuses to work, only loading Step1...

Answer (score 0):

Simply can do like this

```
setInterval( function() { 
var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
var img2 = document.getElementById('img2');

  if ( img1.style.opacity == "0"; ){
     img1.style.opacity = "1";
     img2.style.opacity = "0";
     }
    else if( img2.style.opacity == "0") {
     img1.style.opacity = "0";
     img2.style.opacity = "1";
     }
    else {
    img2.style.opacity = "0";
    img2.style.opacity = "1";
    }

}, 3000 );
```

Make sure your loading this interval after document ready .

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
<script>
var img1;
var img2;

function Step1(){
     img1 = document.getElementById('img1');// after load of page these id's will be available get them in declared varaibles to use
     img2 = document.getElementById('img2');
    img1.style.opacity = "0";
    img2.style.opacity = "1";
    setTimeout(Step2, 3000);
}

function Step2(){
    //alert("Step 2");
    img1.style.opacity = "1";
    img2.style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(Step1, 3000);
}


</script>
<body onload="Step1()"> <!-- call your Step1() function after load of page-->

<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" id="img1">
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" id="img2">
</body>
```

Comment: Describe what you changed and why.